# Oracle For Update & Current Of

Tags: oracle, procedure

I have a procedure where it selects data from a table and inserts into another. Bellow is the procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "CUSTOMER_INCREMENTAL" (
IS   
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO NDB_AML_CUSTOMER 
    (ID, TITLE,...)
  SELECT ID, TITLE,...
    FROM NDB_CUSTOMER_NEW
    WHERE DATE_TIME > (SELECT RUN_DATE FROM CHECK_POINT WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'NDB_CUSTOMER_NEW');

UPDATE CHECK_POINT SET RUN_DATE = SYSDATE WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'NDB_CUSTOMER_NEW';

COMMIT;
END;
/
```

In a scenario where insert happens at 12:41:08 then it will select all records from the source table that exists at that point. And if update statement executes at 12:41:10 then next run will start from that time. And any records added with the `DATE_TIME` of 12:41:09 then those records will not get selected in the next run.

I researched about `For Update` & `Current of` but I'm confused where to use it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Just store sysdate in a variable before `insert` and use that in `update`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "CUSTOMER_INCREMENTAL" (
IS   
v_max_date date;
BEGIN
 v_max_date:=sysdate;

  INSERT INTO NDB_AML_CUSTOMER 
    (ID, TITLE,...)
  SELECT ID, TITLE,...
    FROM NDB_CUSTOMER_NEW
    WHERE DATE_TIME > (SELECT RUN_DATE FROM CHECK_POINT WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'NDB_CUSTOMER_NEW');

  UPDATE CHECK_POINT SET RUN_DATE = v_max_date 
   WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'NDB_CUSTOMER_NEW';


COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Another way is to use `left join`. Assuming `id` is primary key

```
insert into NDB_AML_CUSTOMER (id,title...)
select s.id,s.title,... 
from NBD_CUSTOMER_NEW s 
left join NBD_AML_CUSTOMER t
on s.id=t.id 
where t.id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add *last run date* to sql statement to not miss any increments.

```
vd_next_date date;
    BEGIN
     vd_next_date:=sysdate;
INSERT INTO NDB_AML_CUSTOMER 
    (ID, TITLE,...)
  SELECT ID, TITLE,...
    FROM NDB_CUSTOMER_NEW
    WHERE DATE_TIME >= (SELECT RUN_DATE FROM CHECK_POINT WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'NDB_CUSTOMER_NEW')
AND DATE_TIME < vd_next_date;

UPDATE CHECK_POINT SET RUN_DATE = vd_next_date
   WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'NDB_CUSTOMER_NEW';
```